# Compact manifold taken as an Einstein Manifold

Tags: compactification, kaluza-klein

In Kaluza-Klein theories I often [see](http://www.het.brown.edu/people/danieldf/literary/eric-KKtheories.pdf) that the compact space is assumed to be an Einstein manifold, that is, its Ricci tensor is proportional to its metric.

So, why is this done?

Comment: Could you possibly cite some particular references? I'm sure that would help.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan link on the edit, page 1140